# google deployment manager, can you import files in jinja template that you call directly with --template?

Tags: google-deployment-manager

https://cloud.google.com/deployment-manager/docs/configuration/templates/create-basic-template

I can deploy a template directly like this: `gcloud deployment-manager deployments create a-single-vm --template vm_template.jinja`

But what if that template depends on other files that need to be imported? If using a --config file you can define import in that file and call the template as a resource. But you cant pass parameter/properties to a config file. I want to call a template directly to pass --properties via the command line but that template also needs to import other files.

EDIT: What I needed was a top level jinja template instead of a config. My confusion was that you cant use imports in a jinja template without a schema file- it was failing and I thought it wasnt supported. So the solution was just swap out the config with a jinja template (with schema file) and then I can use --properies

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Maybe you can try **[importing the dependent files](https://cloud.google.com/deployment-manager/docs/step-by-step-guide/create-a-template#importing_templates)** into your config file as follows:

```
imports:
- path: vm-template.jinja
- path: vm-template-2.jinja

# In the resources section below, the properties of the resources are replaced
# with the names of the templates.

resources:
- name: vm-1
  type: vm-template.jinja
- name: vm-2
  type: vm-template-2.jinja
```

> and **[Set Arbitrary Metadata](https://cloud.google.com/deployment-manager/docs/configuration/templates/using-schemas#set_arbitrary_metadata)** insito create a special variable that you can pass and might use in other applications outside of Deployment Manager:

```
properties:
  size:
    type: integer
    default: 2
    description: Number of Mongo Slaves
    variable-x: ultra-secret-sauce
```

> - More info about `gcloud deployment-manager deployments create` optional flags and example can be found **[here.](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/deployment-manager/deployments/create#EXAMPLES)**
> - More info about passing properties using a Schema can be found **[here](https://cloud.google.com/deployment-manager/docs/configuration/templates/using-schemas#example_schema)**

Hope it helps

Comment: hmm could be misunderstanding you but not sure this solves my issue. the real issue is there is no way to pass `--properties` or override arbitrary values of a top level `config` via command line. I *can* do that with templates but not with a yaml config that imports files and templates. ill have to use a makefile/sed to transform my config- which feels silly. DM a full blown scripted deployment engine but it actually feels less configurable then something much more  rigid like cloudformation (which lets you use command line params to replace pretty much any template value)

Comment: Please check out this [Setting values for template properties on the command-line documentation](https://cloud.google.com/deployment-manager/docs/configuration/templates/define-template-properties#templatepropertiescommandline) and let me know if it helps you at all. If you can't find a good solution in the documentation, then you will probably have to go with the workaround doing it with templates.